# Thread.Sleep(0) is not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have just started learning "Threading in C#". 
I found in a book that Thread.Sleep(0) relinquishes the thread’s current time slice immediately, voluntarily
handing over the CPU to other threads.

When I wrote few lines of code to test it. I did not get the expected result. Here the the code I wrote.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Thread A(main thread)";

        Thread thread = new Thread(PrintNumber);
        thread.Name = "Thread B";
        thread.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} | i = {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, i);
        }
    }

    void PrintNumber()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} | i = {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, i);

            if (i == 4)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to my understanding this will print up to 4 in thread B then it will resume the thread A. Next thread schedule is unpredictable.
But this is not happening. While it comes to thread B for the first time sometimes it prints upto 6 sometimes 8 means totally unpredictable.

So is my concept of Theread.Sleep(0) is wrong? Can someone please clarify the concept

Comment: I found the this thread while searching. I overlooked on it and thought it describes different problem. Now I see it asks almost same question as of mine. Sorry for the repetition.

Answer (score 3):

If it *does* free up the thread's slice, that *doesn't mean you can predict where it is going* - it could go to *any process on the computer*. In particular, assuming you have a multi-core machine, the other thread could be being serviced entirely by another core. In the code as shown, it is also likely that `"Thread B"` doesn't even get *started* until the near of `Main`'s loop. Starting a thread is not instantaneous.

There are very few scenarios where `Thread.Sleep(0)` is going to be useful to you, and all of those scenarios would involve *extensive* knowledge of threading and memory models.

Comment: I can not predict which thread will get the time slice when I use Thread.Sleep(0) in a thread. But can it be the same thread which get the time slice again?

Comment: @amitavak sure, why not?

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Yield()` ensures that the next thread being executed is not the current thread.

Comment: I belief Thread.Sleep(0) do the same thing. Only difference is that Thread.Yield() will relinquishes the the time slice only to the thread running on the same processor.

Comment: Highly likely, but not guaranteed.  This is why `Thread.Yield()` returns a `bool`

Comment: Good point. I did not notice it. Thank you.